# Transferring Data from Data Disk (Classic) to New Data Disc

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine, azure-disk

I need to copy specific directories from an Azure data disc (classic) attached to a classic VM to a new data disk attached to a new Linux (Ubuntu) VM. What is the simplest way to move this data (~200GB) from one to the other? The drives are located in different regions. Once the data is copied, the classic resources will be shut down.

Currently, I've attempted to move the data using WINSCP, but of course, that solution is very slow, I've done some research on copying data using AZcopy, but I'm unsure if this is really the simplest solution or if I'm over complicating it by using tools like that.

Comment: Azcopy is a great idea since your data has "large" volume. WINSCP is not a good idea as you have found out yourself. You can also use ADF for this task, but with a staging area in blob or similar. See this q as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250220/how-to-copy-data-to-vm-from-blob-storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Transferring Data from Data Disk (Classic) to New Data Disc

To transfer files from one `Ubuntu VM` to another `VM`, there are multiple ways, but the best approaches are listed below

Method 1: **Using SCP**

> Note: The SCP method should work only if both VMs are able to communicate with each other.

To copy the datadisk files to another VM data Disk.

1. Install `Nettools` on both the `Vms` using below command

```
    sudo apt install net-tools
```

2. Once installed, run the command below to copy all files from `VM1`'s data disk to `VM2`'s data disk.

```bash
 scp -r /data/*  Venkat@10.0.0.7:/data
```

````
 -r: for copy  entire directory
 /data/* : Path of the VM1
 Venkat@10.0.0.7: VM2 username and IP
 /data: Path of VM2
 ```
````

**Result:**
[image]

Files are copied to `VM2` data disk successfully.

[image]

**Method 2** : **AzCopy**

1. Install **AzCopy** on both VM1 and VM2. Follow [this link](https://plzm.blog/201907-azcopy-v10-linux) to install **AzCopy**
   2.Create a `Storage account`with container.
   3 . Log in to `AzCopy` on `VM1` to copy the files to the storage account using the command below.

```
 azcopy copy "/data/*" "https://vmstoragetestdemo.blob.core.windows.net/vmstorage<Storage account-SAS-Token>" --recursive=true
```

> "/data/*"  : path of VM1 Datadisk

**Data copied to Storage account from VM1 datadisk**

[image]

4. Log in to `VM2` using the `azcopy login` command
5. Run the command below to copy the files to the `VM2` data disk.

```
 azcopy copy "https://vmstoragetestdemo.blob.core.windows.net/vmstorage<SAS_TokeN>" "/data" --recursive=true
```

```
/data : VM2 Data disk path
```

Files are copied to `VM2` datadisk successfully.

[image]

Reference: [scp command to copy the files](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scp-command-in-linux-with-examples/)