# How can i copy files from one Azure VM to another using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a file on one Azure VM . I need to copy it to another Azure VM .
How can i do this using powershell ? Any examples ?

I have tried

```
# Source VM details
sourceResourceGroup="<source_resource_group_name>"
sourceVMName="<source_vm_name>"
sourceFilePath="<source_file_path>"

# Destination VM details
destinationResourceGroup="<destination_resource_group_name>"
destinationVMName="<destination_vm_name>"
destinationFilePath="<destination_file_path>"

# Copy the file from source VM to destination VM
az vm run-command invoke -g $sourceResourceGroup -n $sourceVMName - - 
command-id RunShellScript --scripts "scp $sourceFilePath 
 $destinationVMName:$destinationFilePath" --subscription " 
<subscription_id>"
```

but gives error:

```
$destinationVMName:$destina ...
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid 
variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.
```

Or is there an easier script ?

Comment: any script you tried so far @sally?

Comment: yes let me post it in the question

Comment: or to make it easier i run the script from the source vm .. so it would be like copying a local file to a vm on azure , how can i do that ?

Comment: The error is because powershell reads `$destinationVMName:$destinationFilePath` as `$variableScope:variableName` (read about scopes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#using-scope-modifiers) ). To avoid this add a backtick before the `:`, like this: $destinationVMName`:$destinationFilePath

Comment: now gives error:     az : ERROR: (Conflict) Run command OS type 'Linux' does not match the target OS Windows.    the target is a windows machine

Comment: Try to use PowerShell's native commands for Windows VMs and SSH/SCP for Linux VMs

Answer (score 0):

> I have a file on one Azure VM . I need to copy it to another Azure VM.

Alternatively, you can transfer files from one `VM` to another `VM` using the methods below.

Method 1:  **Using SCP**

1. Install  `Nettools`  on Linux  `Vm`  using below command

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

2. Run the following command to copy the file from one VM to another VM

```
 scp  -r /home/Venkat/*  Venkat@20.127.79.83:C:\Temp
```

```
-r: for copy  entire directory
 /home/Venkat/* : Path of the Source VM
 Venkat@20.127.79.83: Destination VM username and IP
C:\Temp: Path of destination VM
```

> Note:  Make sure to enable port 22 before executing the command.

The files have been successfully copied

[image]

**Method 2:** You can also use `SFTP` by using any tool
Ex: **Filezilla**

1. Download and install `FileZilla Client` on windows.
2. Open `FileZilla Client`, go to File, and select Site Manager. It will prompt you for the password of the Linux VM

[image]

[image]

The files have been successfully copied

[image]

Refer [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76988362/transferring-data-from-data-disk-classic-to-new-data-disc/76991654#76991654) for same related issue which is answered by me.

[Use SCP to move files to and from a VM - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/copy-files-to-vm-using-scp)

Comment: I need to auto mate the process from one Windows vm on azure to another windows vm on azure . Using powershell's az cli cmds

Comment: Please confirm, If both the Windows VMs are in same Vnet?